# How to check user by user name is exist in ldap server?

Tags: authentication-authorization

I am using LDAP as my source for users. This works fine, and everyone can simply log in using their LDAP info, and it will create a Drupal user for that person.
However, one of our requirements is during user registration how to check this user already in ldap server or not , means is there any API by which i can check this user already in ldap server on user registration.

Comment: what is your drupal version?

Answer (score 1):

The [LDAP module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ldap) can handle that for you.

Comment: In my scenario user is crating by custom module so i need check user is already in ldap server or not if not then new user created as drupal user.

Comment: Fair enough... the LDAP module contains the only good API I know of, but you can use the php [ldap_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-connect.php) and [ldap_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php) if you want to do it manually